# Error connecting to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Have no idea what I'm doing wrong here but I keep getting the following exception on the `connection.Open();` line:

```
IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)
```

Problem is I have almost the exact same code in another batch job and it works fine. We even pull a spreadsheet from the same location. Does anyone see anything wrong with my connection or query string?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= \\prdhilfs03\l&i-sales&mkt\WORKAREA\Agencyservices\Shared\AIC\Analysts_and_Reporting\Realignments\2014\MassUpdateTesting\ZipCodeTest.xslx;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [Query1$]";


        try
        {
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                //Set connection objects to pull from spreadsheet
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
                connection.Open();
```

For good measure here's a screen shot of the workbook I'm trying to connect to

[image]

Comment: What's the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Did you try to check if you can access the file? 

string xlFile = @"\\prdhilfs03\l&i-sales&mkt\......\ZipCodeTest.xlsx";
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(xlFile) ? "Excel File exists." : "Excel File does not exist.");

Comment: Turns out I had a spelling error in the connection string, thanks. If you want to offer that technique as an answer I'll accept it. (thx again!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to check if you can access the file?

```
string xlFile = @"\\prdhilfs03\l&i-sales&mkt\......\ZipCodeTest.xlsx"; 
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(xlFile) ? "Excel File exists." : "Excel File does not exist.");
```